# Long polling не работает

Tags: php, sql, long-poll, long-polling

Решил добавить подобного рода соединения, как оказалось на примере он работает, а пример заключается в обновление файла. В реальности при работе с базой всё гораздо плачевнее.

Сделал выводы. Вероятнее всего проблема в том, что файл сообщает о своём изменение, в то время... База нет, вероятнее всего надо добавить обновление базы... Вот ссылка на рабочий пример с файлом https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

[image: Не работает]
[image: Работает]

Comment: у вас запрос в базу отправляется до начала цикла единожды, даже при каком-либо изменении данных в БД полученные ранее данные не изменятся.

Comment: как исправить?  перенос в цикл ничего не изменил

Comment: а данные в базе-то меняются? и RedBean разве ответ объектом возвращает? там массив вроде бы. то есть `$data_source_file["date"]`

Comment: Данные в базе меняются. Вы правы, там массив для получения 1 значения делаю так $data_source_file->date;

Comment: просто цикл видимо не запрашивает опять базу, хотя запрос закинул в цикл

Comment: `$data_source_file->date` - обращение к свойству объекта `$data_source_file`, а он у вас, насколько мне известно, массив.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81746/discussion-between-ya-ymer-and--).

Comment: Я хотел бы в чат, но писать я туда не могу)